# Embed Custom Text Fields in OnePAgeCheckOut Magento

Tags: magento

I need to add text fields in Magento OnepageCheckout form. It is not possible to add text fields via admin panel. It is a module installed for one page check out and has its fixed fields so only possible via coding.

I have made changes in

`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/onpagecheckout/onepage/billing.phtml` which is the exact page I am suppose to make changes in but form displays as previous. I did flush the cache every time but not getting whats going wrong.

Comment: you can not directly add filed in billing.phtml please follow this link http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-custom-fields-checkout-page to add custom filed

Comment: I am already following the same link and having above problem in implementing the same tutorial.